# How to automatically open external links in new tab with PHP redirects?

Tags: php, jquery, redirect, hyperlink, external

We currently have some php redirects that go through our tracking software that I would like to open in a new tab on visitors browsers but do not want to go through the entire site manually adding `target="_blank"` or `rel=external`.

Our current links look like this

```
<a href="http://www.website-shown-browser.com" onclick="this.href='http://'+window.location.host+'/visit/redirect.php'">Website</a>
```

I see some examples of jQuery code that automatically identifies external links based on the domain url however we are using these redirects that our hosted on the domain so these links would be filtered out.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible, but not necessarily efficient as opposed to manually adding it in. You would select all a tags and check if their href is external. Then you would set attribute `target` to `_blank` for this element if it is:

```
$('a').each(function() {
   var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
   if(!a.test(this.href)) {
       $(this).click(function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           event.stopPropagation();
           window.open(this.href, '_blank');
       });
   }
});
```

A more efficient way would be to tweak your selector to only select a tags starting with `http://`, but this will only work if your internal links are not prefixed with `http://`:

```
$("#content a[href^='http://']").attr("target","_blank");
```